# Exclude underscore from a project that uses it (browserify)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm, browserify

I'm trying to make a npm project browser-compatible with browserify. One of the dependencies of that project is underscore. I want to make browserify build that project without including underscore in the destination file, so I'm using this in my grunt config:

```
options: {
    exclude: {
        'underscore'
    }
}
```

This makes the destination file smaller (+/- the size of underscore), but when I try to run the project in a browser, I get this:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
```

Note that I'm getting this even if I included `underscore` before including my project (with a `<script>` tag)

How can I make browserify understand that underscore will be loaded externally by me?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Uncaught Error` you are getting is a result of including `underscore` in the exclude options? Also, where are you using the custom module and what file path are you using to include `underscore` in your project?

Comment: Are you still `require`ing underscore? If so, that'll be the problem. If you're loading it yourself via a `<script>` tag, you'll only be able to access it via the `_` global variable.

Comment: @SamHolmes I'm completely sure. The moment I comment the "exclude underscore", the `dist.js` file starts working again. The encaught error comes from the `dist.js`, not from the code from which I'm trying to use the module.

Comment: @JimO'Brien The only thing that I'm requiring is my module. Underscore is being required internally by the `dist.js`. There must be some way to tell browserify that underscore is actually `_`, but I don't know how.

Comment: I'd consider using the [`--standalone` mode](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) on browserify, and try using an external module loader inline. That said, if you're looking to simply shrink the size of your output bundle, I'd use [`lodash`](http://lodash.com) instead, and only require the individual functions you need (see the Installation section on that page).

Comment: @JimO'Brien underscore is just one of the libraries I'm trying to scratch from the `dist.js`. Regarding the standalone option, I tried running it, but the `dist.js` size didn't change, which makes me think that underscore is still inside. How should I use that standalone command to remove underscore?

Comment: Apologies, I misinterpreted the documentation on standalone - it doesn't do what I thought it did. Have you read the ['excluding' section in the browserify handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#excluding)?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that right now, but it doesn't seem to be working. I think the problem is that the loaded undescore is not a bundle, but plain JS, so browserify can't `require` it.

Answer (score 2):

That was easier than I though. I just had to replace `exclude` with `ignore`. Browserify took care about everything else :)